# Getting AIC of lognormal distributions using scikit's GMM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distribution, model-fitting, gaussian-mixture-model

I have the following data generated using:

```
from scipy.stats import skewnorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

numValues = 10000
maxValue = 100
skewness = -5   
data = skewnorm.rvs(a = skewness,loc=maxValue, size=numValues)
```

[image]

for guassian model, I have calculated the AIC from below:

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components = 1).fit(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
gmm_aic = gmm.aic(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
gmm_bic = gmm.bic(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
```

for lognormal model, I took the logarithm of data and fitted a guassian from below:

```
log_gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components = 1).fit(X=np.expand_dims(np.log(data),1))
```

and calculated AIC for this model on the **data** and not on **np.log(data)**

```
log_gmm_aic = log_gmm.aic(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
log_gmm_bic = log_gmm.bic(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
```

This way, my AIC and BIC values in both the cases are:

```
Guassian - AIC: 18790.27 BIC:18804.69 

lognormal - AIC: 2231500479614.06 BIC:2231500479628.48
```

The values seem incomparable.
What am I doing wrong if I want to calculate lognormal model's AIC and BIC?

Comment: Maybe better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you should not compare aic of models that have different scales of response variables. See post like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190839/aic-bic-and-data-transformation) or [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462759/can-aic-bic-be-used-to-compare-models-that-differ-by-transformation-of-response).

So for example you can compare

```
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components = 1).fit(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
print(gmm.aic(X=np.expand_dims(data,1)))

gmm2 = GaussianMixture(n_components = 2).fit(X=np.expand_dims(data,1))
print(gmm2.aic(X=np.expand_dims(data,1)))

18753.718210403502
17498.87614003799
```

You can see that the first model has a better BIC than the second.

A bit further on why you are getting weird values. For the non-log model, the estimated parameters are:

```
gmm.means_
array([[99.2174906]])

gmm.covariances_
array([[[0.38499364]]])
```

For your so called log-normal data, your input data is on the log scale and you can see that the estimated parameters are on the log scale:

```
log_gmm.means_
array([[4.59729469]])

log_gmm.covariances_
array([[[4.0321591e-05]]])
```

The BIC and AIC are derived from the log likelihood of the model, and you have to use your input data, because you want to know given a value on the log space, what is it's probability of belonging to a cluster.

However you instantly notice that you get a negative aic:

```
log_gmm.bic(np.log(np.expand_dims(data,1)))
Out[59]: -73122.88028438632
```

The reason for this is that your variance is extremely small, so in estimating the probabilities, [see source code for gmm](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/mixture/_gaussian_mixture.py#L394), most of your probabilities exceed 1, making the aic positive. See [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok) for more details on pdf values > 1.

Lastly, if you want to know whether your response variable or distribution is better log-transformed, you don't need to use a gaussian mixture. You can use a qqplot or basically [check whether changes are multiplicative or additive](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18844/when-and-why-should-you-take-the-log-of-a-distribution-of-numbers).